# JQuery on-click get all field's value except this one's closest field's value (In multiple row)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and every row of the table contain a input-field and a input-button. 
I am looking for easier way to select all "input fields" except current row's "input field" by clicking "input button" of each row.
All input fields contain same name, row is dynamically generated and not limited.

**Sample Html:**

```
 <table>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Apple "></td>
          <td><input type="button" onclick="restOf(this)" value="Get Value"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Banana "></td>
          <td><input type="button" onclick="restOf(this)" value="Get Value"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Orange "></td>
          <td><input type="button" onclick="restOf(this)" value="Get Value"></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

**My js -(by using "not()" and "closest()" function)**

```
<script>
  function restOf(obj){
    var selected    = '';
    $("input[name='name[]']").not($(obj).closest("input[name='name[]']")).each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
        selected += value;
     });
     alert(selected);
  }
</script>
```

**Expected result:**

```
If clicked Apple  row's "Get Value" button  = "Banana Orange"
If clicked Banana row's "Get Value" button  = "Apple  Orange"
If clicked Orange row's "Get Value" button  = "Apple  Banana"
```

Answer (score 0):

closest check the passed selector against the element itself and its ancestors. In you case, the text input is a "cousin" of the button (the child of the sibling of the button parent), not an ancestor.

So try replacing putting in the not() method:

```
$(obj).closest('td').siblings().children()
```